# Accessing AppState in AppDelegate with SwiftUI's new iOS 14 life cycle

Tags: swift, swiftui, state, appdelegate, ios14

I'm using SwiftUI's new app lifecycle coming in iOS 14.

However, I'm stuck at how to access my *AppState* (single source of truth) object in the *AppDelegate*.
I need the *AppDelegate* to run code on startup and register for notifications (`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`, `didReceiveRemoteNotification`) etc.

I am aware of `@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor` but then I can not e.g. pass an object through to the *AppDelegate* with a constructor. I guess the other way round (creating the *AppState* in the *AppDelegate* and then accessing it in *MyApp*) does not work either.

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    @State var appState = AppState()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environmentObject(appState)
        }
    }
}
```

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        // access appState here...
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        // ...and access appState here
    }
}
```

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    // Singe source of truth...
    @Published var user: User()
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Maybe there is currently no way to achieve this, and I need to convert my app to use the old UIKit lifecycle?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use shared instance for `AppState`

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = AppState()    // << here !!

    // Singe source of truth...
    @Published var user = User()
}
```

so you can use it everywhere

```
struct MyApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    @StateObject var appState = AppState.shared

    // ... other code
}
```

and

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        // ...and access appState here

        AppState.shared.user = ...
    }
```

Comment: That's a nice approach, what about manipulating the shared object inside the AppDelegate, does the @StateObject variable emit the updates to the views?

Comment: Yes, SwiftUI 2.0 StateObject is exactly for that purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Is there a reason why you need to run the code in app delegate?
If you are using new app lifecycle, why not trigger your code from `WindowGroup.onChange()`

```
struct MyScene: Scene {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    @StateObject private var cache = DataCache()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MyRootView()
        }
        .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newScenePhase in
            if newScenePhase == .background {
                cache.empty()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Apple Documentation Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/windowgroup/onchange(of:perform:))

[Managing scenes in SwiftUI by Majid](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/08/26/managing-scenes-in-swiftui/)

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I need to run code for `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` and `didReceiveRemoteNotification`, which are only available in the AppDelegate if I am not mistaken?

Comment: @Mister22, if that's your use case, I think Asperi's solution is a sound one. I think I personally would also take that route.