# How to access the Swift struct conforming to the App protocol from the AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

Sorry if this is an answered question but 'Swift' 'App' and 'Protocol' are all too generic terms to warrant a good result.

I have socket emulator app that I use for testing that has a App struct with the server as a property:

```
@main
struct RelayEmulatorApp: App {

   var socketServer : SocketServer


   @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
}
```

And then in my appDelegate I override applicationWillTerminate where I would like to gracefully close the socket server.  I'm finding since the socketServer's deinit has the calls to NIO's syncShutdownGracefully which is not called on app termination, I have to call it explicitly in AppDelegate (the OS apparently is slow to close the socket for a terminated process when the process doesn't do so--I think).

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

  func applicationWillTerminate(_ notification: Notification) {

  }

}
```

But how in the AppDelegate can I reference the instance of the App struct (which I imagine is being instantiated by the @main annotation) and thus its properties to gracefully shutdown the socket?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63597866/12299030?

Comment: Well, it could but I think I prefer Tarun Tyagi's solution of injecting the bits needed over depending on a singleton GOD AppState object as suggested in that solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `RelayEmulatorApp`, after the `socketServer` has been instantiated, you can assign it to the `appDelegate` variable.

```
@main
struct RelayEmulatorApp: App {

   var socketServer : SocketServer

   @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

   func someFunctionThatInstantiatesSocketServer() {
       /// Instantiation for sockectServer is done at this point
       appDelegate.socketServer = socketServer
   }
}
```

Then you will have access to this instance in `AppDelegate` class.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

  var socketServer : SocketServer

  func applicationWillTerminate(_ notification: Notification) {
      /// socketServer.close() 
  }

}
```

Comment: Ah, good suggestion.  Its much better to inject what is needed as you suggest over me trying to depend on the parent.

Comment: Very interesting! Is this documented?